# Negate infavorites

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I can use `infavorites:mine is:question [sometag]` to search all question having `sometag` tag I've marked as favorites.

Can I negate this and find all questions having `sometag` tag I've not marked as favorites?

EDIT: I've tried to use `-` operator that works for tags, but if I use it with `infavorites` it yields questions marked as favorites as well.

Comment: You only have 2 favourites, is this even a problem? People generally have few favourites so just ignoring them is probably easier no? I can't really see the benefit for this.

Comment: I've marked two questions for testing purposes only.

Comment: Here is a quick query I created to get you question with specified tags that you haven't favorited: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/811641/posts-with-tags-not-in-favorites

Comment: We should create a new operator for this, `unfavorites:`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I have 767 favorite questions :D

Comment: Did anything change on this?