# How can I mark questions as already visited by me?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I'd like to read most upvoted questions about particular technology, since studying answers to these common problems can be quite insightful. I'd like to be able to mark questions I've already visited so I can filter them out in my subsequent search queries and proceed to next ones I haven't seen yet. Managing a big list of visited URLs outside of Stack Overflow is possible, but it is a bit cumbersome. Is there a way I can mark questions on the site so they can be filtered out...?

I've thought that it might be possible to use the bookmarking feature for that, because you can bookmark a question and then filter these with `inbookmarks:mine`. It is, however, impossible to negate this and find questions that are not bookmarked (see [this old question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363854/negate-infavorites)).

Is there anything that can be used to mark questions and have them removed from search? If not, would it be possible to create some `notinbookmarks` operator?

Comment: The most upvoted questions don't change very often, really you just need to keep track of where you are in the list.

Comment: Writing a simple user script to keep track would not be difficult or time consuming

Comment: [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app+or+library)?

Comment: I was going to suggest not clearing Stack Exchange from your browser history but [there isn't a visible difference in visited and unvisited link colors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392188/please-revert-the-anchor-coloring-change/392199#392199). If you're able to override link colors in your browser that might still work though.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Similar to ignored tags, but for individual questions. Not sure I would ever use it, but it's interesting

Comment: I know of a userscript that's in the ballpark to this functionality called [Activity Indicator](https://stackapps.com/questions/9148/activity-indicator-see-if-you-participated-in-a-qa-at-a-glance), but it unfortunately doesn't track viewed status.

Comment: pssst... I accept feature requests :) Cannot guarantee an ETA, but likely sooner than 6 to 8 time units

Comment: @OlegValter I might throw one your way soon, I noticed today that the script doesn't apply to meta sites, which is something I'd find really useful! That'd be an easy adjustment to make too.

Comment: @zcoop98 too late for that ^_^ Meta sites are now included in the `@match` headers of the Activity Indicator script - needed to make an update to an update to a [utility package of mine](https://stackapps.com/q/9088/78873) for generating userscript metadata (PRs/feedback welcome) first.